# Twitch bot lurker welcome

Tags: video-streaming, bots, twitch, mirc

I am a new-coming streamer, and i saw this on a few channels and wondered how to do it:

As soon as someone joins the channel, the name gets pulled, and welcomed in chat by the bot, this stops people from lurking and gets them to chat with other people, therefore making my channel more interactive.

I know i have to set up mIRC and i am doing so now, but what do i do after i have it downloaded to set this feature up?

Thank you all very much for answering this question i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Open mIRC, connect, go to remotes, add a remote and add this in and click ok.

```
on *:join:#: { 
msg # $nick $+ , welcome to the channel.
}
```

Make a new account for your bot as well, it gets complicated when it is on your streaming account.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc/introduction, and when you learn some basic stuff there, you can go to http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc/on_events/on_join. This is the event that will trigger when someone joins a channel.

If you still have questions you can reply here.